# Inclusion confusion in the category of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose I have a Hilbert space $H$ and a linear subspace $V\subset H$ with its inner product inherited from $H$. The spaces are in particular sets, so I may consider the inclusion map $i:V\hookrightarrow H$. Of course for any element $v\in V\subset H$, $||i(v)||=||v||$ since the norm is inherited. But this means that $i$ is an isometry, whence $V$ is a complete subspace and also therefore closed.

But we know there are subspaces of Hilbert spaces which are [not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057526/an-example-of-non-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space). These are not open either, but there must be some error in my arguments above. Where is my mistake?

Taking $H,V$ to be Banach spaces doesn't change anything I think.

Comment: Very catchy title!

Comment: I'm missing something. Why should the fact that $i$ is an isometry imply that $V$ is a complete subspace of $H$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate  how you concluded V to be complete?

Comment: If $i$ were a _surjective_ isometry it would follow that $V$ was complete...

Comment: Thank you! I'm thinking like this. $H$ is complete, so its Cauchy sequences converge. If we take a Cauchy sequence in $V$ and then consider the norm of the difference of adjacent elements far along, we get $\epsilon>||v_{j+1}-v_j||=||i(v_{j+1}-v_j)||=||i(v_{j+1})-i(v_j)||$ by linearity. So $\{ i(v_j) \}$ is Cauchy in $H$, where it converges to some $h\in H$. Ah. Do I now need that $h$ is in the image of $i$..

Comment: I see, I think I confused the whole space $H$ with the image of $i$, meaning $i(V)=V$.